# Jagged points on 2d model after rigging and trying to move bones

Tags: rigging

I am quite new to blender 2d/3d, and I did this foot for a character.

I watched some tuts on YT about rigging and everything seemed fine, but then I realized that there are these jagged points when I try to bend the bones. So, I tried to weight paint the bones right (I had then assigned with automatic weights first).

Can you tell me where I am making my mistake or is there even a way out of this?

[image: Mesh]

Edit Mode. I know that the mesh has too many vertex, but I thought I would need them for good weight painting

[image: Edit Mode. I know that the mesh has too many vertex, but I thought I would need them for good weight painting]

And here is the problem:
[image: Problem Nr.1]
[image: Problem Nr.24]

Weight painting:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You don't need more vertices for good weight painting, and in fact using fewer vertices is usually better.  You should be selecting the spiky verts in weight paint/vertex mode and inspecting their weights by looking on sidebar/item/vertex weights, and compare with their neighbors to figure out what the problem is.  Probably, with a mesh this dense, you could just run a weights->smooth/1.0 expand on the spiky verts to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I have this new foot now, with fewer vertex. I think though, that I can't do a proper weight paint here, bc there are no vertex inside the mesh, but only outside?
Actually, I tried this one, and then I subdivided the mesh to have these lots of vertex. was that wrong and how can I weight paint properly on this one?
[image]

Actually, the automatic weights do well, but for each bone, it is affecting also the other parts. when I try to paint it, it makes weird changes due to the lack of vertex.
But I know that I can't weight paint it properly without having these jagged edges again. :(

[image]
[image]